# React.js with Express: Render a simple component on the client-side while using Express as a server?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I'm new to ReactJS and Node.js and I'm definitely stuck. My problem is that I can't render my simple React component in my index.html file. When i write `webpack` in the terminal, it outputs a `bundle.js` file. Then when I start the webpack-dev-server using the `npm start` script, it runs and I'm able to go to `localhost:3000`, it outputs this:
[Image of output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z8THP.png). Meaning it doesn't output the `<div id="app"></div>`.

And when I go to `localhost:3000/bundle/bundle.js` it outputs the `bundle.js` file in the browser.

I've also tried to start the server using `node app.js` in the terminal, and it starts the server and renders the `index.html` file when I go to `localhost:3000`, but it doesn't load the `bundle.js` script, instead it's a 404. I've tried writing the src-attribute in mutliple ways (../bundle/bundle.js etc.) but I can't get it to work.

**Folder structure below. I hope it's readable**

```
root
  bundle
    bundle.js
  src
    App.jsx
  static
    index.html
  app.js
  package.json
  webpack.config.js
```

Anyways, I've searched for hours and I can't find any solution, so I hope someone can help me out. I'll post the relevant files below. Cheers!

**app.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var user = require('./models/userModel');

var app = express();

app.use(express.static('static'));

var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.listen(port);
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Forum</title>
</head>

<body>
  <script src="../bundle/bundle.js"></script>
  <div id="app"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

**App.jsx**

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');

var Test = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return <h1>Hello world</h1>;
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(<Test />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');

var DEV = path.resolve(__dirname, 'src');
var OUTPUT = path.resolve(__dirname, 'bundle');

var Config = {
  entry: [
    'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:3000',
    'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
    DEV + '/App.jsx'
  ],
  module: {
    loaders: [{
      exclude: './node_modules/',
      loaders: ['react-hot', 'babel-loader']
    }]
  },
  output: {
    path: OUTPUT,
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  devServer: {
    inline: true
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()
  ]
};

module.exports = Config;
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "forum",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --port 3000"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.15.2",
    "express": "^4.14.0",
    "mongoose": "^4.7.6",
    "react": "^15.4.1",
    "react-dom": "^15.4.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel": "^6.5.2",
    "babel-core": "^6.21.0",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.10",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.18.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.16.0",
    "react-hot-loader": "^1.3.1",
    "webpack": "^1.14.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.16.2"
  },
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "es2015",
      "react"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: have you tried to set a default route? like this 
app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendfile('./statics/index.html');
});

Comment: @EthanLi No need for routing if you only want to serve static files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You serve `/static` but not `/bundle`. They are two separate folders in your root. One way to fix this would be to output your bundle into the `/static` folder that you serve:

```
// webpack.config.js
var OUTPUT = path.resolve(__dirname, 'static/bundle');
```

Then you should be able to load in your `bundle.js` like this:

```
<script src="/bundle/bundle.js"></script>
```